# Limit of the logarithm of the expansion of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, large-deviation-theory

(Probably a better title is needed)

The following statements are given as hypothesis:

1) Suppose we know that a function $e^{f(t)}$ can be expanded in the following way:
\begin{equation}
e^{f\left(t\right)}=e^{tc}a+e^{tc'}a'+...
\end{equation}
2) we know that $c-c'=w$ so that
\begin{equation}
e^{f\left(t\right)}=e^{tc}\left[a+e^{-tw}a'+...\right]
\end{equation}
3) and also that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{f\left(t\right)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{tc}\left[a+e^{-tw}a'+...\right]=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{tc}a
\end{equation}
then $e^{f\left(t\right)}=e^{tc}\left[a+O\left(e^{-tw}\right)\right]$

> Is it in general true or under some conditions of $c,a,f(t)$ that
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\left[e^{f\left(t\right)}\right]=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{t}\ln\left[e^{tc}a\right]
> \end{equation}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ is continuous and the limit $$\lim_{t\to\infty} h(t)$$ exists, then $$\lim_{t\to\infty} g(h(t)) = g(\lim_{t\to\infty} h(t)).$$

Comment: Thanks! Check the edit ;-)